# How do you DELETE rows in a mysql table that have a field IN the results of another query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, delete-row, sql-delete

Here's what the statement looks like:

```
DELETE FROM videoswatched vw2 
 WHERE vw2.userID IN ( SELECT vw.userID 
                         FROM videoswatched vw
                         JOIN users u ON vw.userID=u.userID
                        WHERE u.companyID = 1000
                     GROUP BY userID )
```

That looks decent to me, and the SELECT statement works on its own (producing rows with a single column 'userID'.

Basically, I want to delete entries in the 'videoswatched' table where the userID in the videoswatched entry, after joining to the users table, is found to have companyID=1000.

How can I do this without getting the error in my sql syntax? It says the error is near:

```
vw2 WHERE vw2.userID IN (
    SELECT vw.userID FROM videoswatched vw
    JOIN users u
```

and on line 1.

Comment: There's no reason to assign it an alias, try removing the vw2 and just make it videoswatched WHERE `userID` IN

Comment: Not relevant to the error but the `GROUP BY userID` seems superfluous as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has already been answered in the comments: You need to remove the table alias, it is not allowed in [MySQL's DELETE statement syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) (and there is no need for it, either).

Edit: BTW, Try this (coding from memory, might be wrong):

```
DELETE vw.*
FROM videoswatched vw
INNER JOIN users u ON vw.userID = u.userID
WHERE u.companyID = 1000;
```

Comment: thanks a lot!
the only adjustment i'd make is taking away the 'INNER' in "INNER JOIN", only cuz i don't think its useful in a delete

Comment: @gsquare - INNER JOIN and JOIN are the same thing. If not specified a JOIN defaults to INNER.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) says

> Note
>
> If you declare an alias for a table,
>   you must use the alias when referring
>   to the table:
>
> DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE
>   ...

So, you could try

```
DELETE vm2 FROM videoswatched vw2 WHERE vw2.userID IN (
SELECT vw.userID FROM videoswatched vw
JOIN users u
ON vw.userID=u.userID
WHERE u.companyID=1000
GROUP BY userID
)
```

But as mentioned in the comments you can simply do away with the alias

```
DELETE FROM videoswatched WHERE userID IN (
SELECT vw.userID FROM videoswatched vw
JOIN users u
ON vw.userID=u.userID
WHERE u.companyID=1000
GROUP BY userID
)
```